# Cannot perform HTTPS local tunnel fith Fiddler2 - Problems with certificates

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, fiddler

I am trying to create an HTTPS-tunnel on my machine. My intention is having all requests to `https://localhost:8888/<something>` (the port where Fiddler is listening to) be directed to `https://myserver.net/<something>`. I am using the following script as per [Fiddler doc](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse):

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
  // <Fiddler 2 preexisting code>
  // HTTPS redirect ----------------------- 
  if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && 
     (oSession.PathAndQuery == "localhost:8888")) 
  {
    oSession.PathAndQuery = "myserver.net:443";
  }
  if (oSession.HostnameIs("localhost")) 
    oSession.hostname = "myserver.net";
  // --------------------------------------
  // <Fiddler 2 preexisting code>
}
```

Also in Fiddler settings I checked the decryption check and installed certificates as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I restart Fiddler, it prompts me to install its fake certificates, I agree. I can see the certificate in my Windows Certificate System Repository when using `certmgr`. It is a self-signed certificate.

So What I do is opening a browser and type: `https://localhost:8888/mypage.html`, and what I get is an error. Internet Explorer reports this:

> Error: Mismatched Address. The security certificate presented by this
>   website was issued for a different website's address. This problem
>   might indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data...

When I get certificate info (basically the certificate presented by the contacted host is being rejected, the same certificate can be displayed), I can see that the rejected certificate was issued by Fiddler and the subject is **myserver.net**.

[image]

So the certificate is ok because it is certifying `myserver.net`, I see that the problem is that probably my browser was expecting a certificate whose subject is `localhost`. Is it true?

How to handle this situation?

### Assumption

I can understand that the problem is a certificate being issued for a website which I did not ask for. So the solution would be using a certificate certifying `localhost:8888`?

Comment: Of course `myserver.net` is listening on port 443 and is HTTPS enabled. if I try to navigate to its address I can get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certificate is valid if it is directly or indirectly (via intermediate certificates) signed by a trusted CA *and* if the hostname matches the certificate. If the last condition would not be enforced anybody with a valid certificate from a trusted CA could incorporate any other site.

To make use of fiddler and not run into this problem you should configure your browser to use fiddler as a web proxy and then use the real URL inside the browser instead of ip:port of fiddler.

Comment: Ok! So my questionn is... How am I supposed with Fiddler to HTTPS tunnel a communication?

Comment: You don't access fiddler directly as HTTP server, but configure it as proxy inside the browser and then access the real URL `https://example.com`.

Comment: Please could you post your comment as part of the answer? That would answer my question making me able to mark your answer as valid :)

Comment: Sorry Steffen I was thinking about one thing... I am trying to create a proxy, so it means that I must ask for an address and I should get a response from another server... Actually Fiddler is also proving an example here: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse

I do not want to type the same address to get a resource from that address...

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand your problem: You don't want to use the hostname of the real server but want the browser to accept a certificate issued (by fiddler) to the real server? I think this will not be possible because of name mismatch. What you might instead use is nginx or other reverse proxies to listen to one name and provide the certificate matching the name, but then forward the requests to another host.

Comment: Yes I understand it, sorry I just ha to think about the situation a little bit more. thank you!